# Xamarin add new line to JSON

Tags: c#, xamarin

wondering if anybody can help with a solution I am looking for. In my Xamarin project, I have a 'add another line' button which adds another stack layout underneath it with the same controls as the first one. I want to save the new added one to JSON but not sure where to start, has anybody done this before?

I have added the first stack to json but i need it to reckonise the new ones on the button press. (sorry if it does not make sense)

Page.xaml Code:

```
<Grid Margin="0, 30, 0, 30">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label x:Name="NameLabel" Text="Name" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label x:Name="ArrivalLabel" Text="Arrival" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label x:Name="DescriptionLabel" Text="Description" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label x:Name="DepartLabel" Text="Depart" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label x:Name="SignLabel" Text="Sign" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" />
            </Grid>
            <StackLayout x:Name="AddMoreNotes">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Entry x:Name="Name" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <TimePicker x:Name="Arrival" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <Entry x:Name="Description" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <TimePicker x:Name="Depart" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <Entry x:Name="Sign" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
                <!--Add More View Spawns Here Do Not Change-->
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Button x:Name="AddMoreButton" Text="Add More" FontSize="16" BorderRadius="6" Clicked="AddMoreButton_Clicked" />
            </StackLayout>
```

Page.xaml.cs Code:

```
private void AddMoreButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddMoreNotes.Children.Add(new AttendanceAddMoreView()
        {

        });
    }

    private void SubmitButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var attendanceChecklist = new AttendanceChecklist();
        var AttentionOf1 = new List<AttentionOf>();
        var AttendanceSection1 = new List<AttendanceSection>();

        attendanceChecklist.TheDate = TheDate.Date;
        attendanceChecklist.AttendanceNumber = AttendanceNumber.Text;
        attendanceChecklist.EmployeeName = EmployeeName.Text;

        AttentionOf1.Add(new AttentionOf()
        {
            FirstName = FirstName.Text,
            LastName = LastName.Text,
            AddressLine1 = AddressLine1.Text,
            AddressLine2 = AddressLine2.Text,
            CityOrTown = CityOrTown.Text,
            County = County.Text,
            Postcode = Postcode.Text,
            ContractTitleOrRef = ContractTitleOrRef.Text,
            CustomerName = CustomerName.Text,
            SiteContact = SiteContact.Text,
        });

        AttendanceSection1.Add(new AttendanceSection()
        {
            Name = Name.Text,
            Arrival = Arrival.Time,
            Description = Description.Text,
            Depart = Depart.Time,
            Sign = Sign.Text
        });

        attendanceChecklist.attentionOf = AttentionOf1;
        attendanceChecklist.attendanceSection = AttendanceSection1;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attendanceChecklist, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

        var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "AttendanceNote.json");
        File.WriteAllText(filename, json);
        }
```

Edit:

added new code

```
public string LargerJsonString;

private void AddMoreButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddMoreNotes.Children.Add(new AttendanceAddMoreView()
        {

        });
        StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AddMoreNotes), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        LargerJsonString += content;
    }
```

Comment: You just add your data to the respective object and then serialize that object and your json is ready

Comment: @G.hakim when filling in the entry's and pressing the submit button it does not appear in the json only the first one that is there

Comment: Are you sure you are adding it to a list of objects properly if yes then can you point me out where are you doing that in the code above

Comment: @G.hakim I don't think I am as you can see in the Page.xaml.cs I add the first AttendanceSection1 with the fields in but I am not sure how to add ones that clone into the page on the button press.

Comment: Can you give me a brief explanation of the code you have here I think I can give you a better solution altogether!

Comment: So basically, on the XAML I have a 5 column grid which includes the following objects  (Entry, Time Picker, Entry, Time Picker, Entry) which the user has to fill out but this section can be added multiple times so when the user clicks on the 'add more button' it basically adds the same grid with the same objects. so when the user clicked the submit button it saves to serializes to JSON so in the above code its adding the first AttendanceSection1 which is the first grid but when i click on the add more button it needs to add the new grid values to the JSON if theres more then one.

Comment: For now, just check out how Xamarin.Forms Listview works maybe you might not even need my help once you get familiar with it.

Comment: @G.hakim are you able to upload now ?

Comment: Yes but i will be adding the code as per my understanding it will just be a skeleton you might have to make a lot of changes in it

Comment: @G.hakim ok no problem let's see

Comment: I have added the code as promised kindly take a look

Comment: Any updates did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Start this I have done this in MVVM and hence you might have to use that if you are not already using it.

Now I made a dummy layout and a dummy model which can be seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"             
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             
         x:Class="XamarinCertUnderstanding.Views.MainPage">
<StackLayout Margin="0, 15, 0, 0">
    <Button VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BorderColor="Black" BackgroundColor="Blue" Command="{Binding AddButton}" TextColor="Green" Text="Add Button"/>
    <ListView x:Name="MainList" ItemsSource="{Binding DefaultModels}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasUnevenRows="True"
              SeparatorVisibility="Default" Margin="0, 15, 0, 0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Spacing="10" >
                            <Entry  Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Name" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                            <TimePicker  Time="{Binding Arrival,Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="20"  BackgroundColor="White"/>
                            <Entry  Text="{Binding Description,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Description" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                            <TimePicker  Time="{Binding Depart,Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                            <Entry  FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Sign,Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Sign" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I am using BindingMode as TwoWay so that any change on the View is reflected to the ViewModel Collection and Vice versa

The DummyModel that I use is as shown below:

```
  public class DefaultModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string userName = string.Empty;
    private string description = string.Empty;
    private string sign = string.Empty;
    private TimeSpan arrival = TimeSpan.Zero;
    private TimeSpan depart = TimeSpan.Zero;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return userName;
        }
        set
        {
            userName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan Arrival
    {
        get
        {
            return arrival;
        }
        set
        {
            arrival = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Arrival));
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return description;
        }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan Depart
    {
        get
        {
            return depart;
        }
        set
        {
            depart = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Depart));
        }
    }

    public string Sign
    {
        get
        {
            return sign;
        }
        set
        {
            sign = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Sign));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify any changes in the property. For better understanding check this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

In your `MainPage.Xaml.cs` set the BindingContext to `MainViewModel` in the constructor.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now in your ViewModel do the following:

```
 public class MainViewModel : BindableObject
{
    public Command AddButton { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<DefaultModel> defaultModels;
    public ObservableCollection<DefaultModel> DefaultModels
    {
        get { return defaultModels; }
        set
        {
            defaultModels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DefaultModels));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        DefaultModels = new ObservableCollection<DefaultModel>();
        DefaultModels.Add(new DefaultModel());
        AddButton = new Command(AddButtonCommand);
    }

    private void AddButtonCommand(object obj)
    {
        DefaultModels.Add(new DefaultModel());
    }
}
```

Now how this works is quite simple on AddButton Click I call the `AddButtonCommand` and I initialize a blank object and add it to the ObservableCollection which then updates my View and adds another set of controls as far as get this data goes you can get all the data from your `DefaultModels` collection.

Goodluck

Revert in case of queries

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not able to comment so I'll leave my thoughts here: first off I'd use a ListView as it allows you to easily bind items to your ListView. A little example beneath

```
<ListView x:Name="MainList" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="Default" Margin="0, 15, 0, 0" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshingMessages}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            Put your code in here
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

This should work if you're doing this in the MVVM, Model View to View Model, structure which makes life a lot easier. However I don't believe this is a necessity. In the case of you wanting to add another line to your JSON, I see you're already using JsonConvert, so can't you deserialize the the JSON to a list of the object and loop through the list and output a number of items on your screen?

```
string JsonContent = await WhateverYourJsonIs.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
var something = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WhateverYourObjectIsCalled>>(JsonContent)
```

I'm not exactly sure if that's what you're trying to achieve, if not, let me know and I'll try to help! In this case, WhateverYourJsonIs would most likely need to be a string of Json, you might not need that line, in my case of returning information from a server I do need to read it as a string however you may not need to as it may already be a string, that would be a little testing on your part as I haven't done it this way so I've grabbed snips from my code. Hope this helps!

Edit:

If you serialize your object and have a list of string using this method

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewItem), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

That'll convert it into Json for you, you can then append it on the end of a larger Json string for example:

```
LargerJsonString += content
```

And then add it to your File. Alternatively you could use something such as SQLite and store it in a local Database Table? This is the method I use

Edit 2

So I did a little digging on the Docs.Microsoft to try and find what you're using for "File.WriteAllText" and I found this method which appends extra text onto the end of the file

```
string appendText = "This is extra text" + Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);
```

Try using this rather than WriteAll

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187948/discussion-on-answer-by-tipsydriver-xamarin-add-new-line-to-json). Please remember to [edit] the answer to include any relevant information from the chat discussion.